# What font is Frontiers journal using?

Tags: paper-submission

I am looking for the name of the font used in the body of published articles of Frontiers journal, as shown in the downloadable article [here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnsys.2017.00061/full).

I tried Helvetica Neue, MinionPro, and Times. Please note the difference in letter 'y' [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UyYh.png).

Comment: Which specific journal? Please share an example article link.

Comment: There seems to be at least 4 journals with the name Frontiers.  Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Please see link. Thank you. https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnsys.2017.00061/full

Comment: the webpage or the PDF and the body or the abstract?

Comment: In the body. Again, thank you for requesting further clarification.

Comment: How did you produce that Minion Pro sample? If you try [here](https://fontoteka.com/font/minion-pro-regular) the y is much closer to the text in the article, and other samples I can find on the internet agree.

Comment: You are right, Federico. Having downloaded the font from the source you linked and restarted Word, letter "y" stands corrected. I do not know why existing MinionPro in Word yielded unsatisfactory results. Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps Museo Sans.  When I look at the HTML, I see these references:  font-awesome, museo-sans, museo-slab, open-sans .

Answer (score 1):

On my pdf reader (Evince on Ubuntu), I can simply click on `Hamburger menu -> properties -> Fonts` to discover that the fonts are Helvetica Neue LT Standard and Minion Pro. The others in the list are math fonts.

[image]

Comment: Adobe Reader has the same feature, however, neither MinionPro nor Helvetica Neue match the font of the body. As for the other fonts, I cannot find them in font directories. Thank you.

Comment: To me the body font looks quite similar to Minion Pro. Anyhow I suggest specifying in your question what you have already tried and why the results are not satisfying. This will prevent duplicate efforts and make your question clearer.

Comment: I just uploaded an image noting the difference between the article body and MinionPro. But yes, I agree that MinionPro probably approximates it best.